# Scalable client server communication

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, networking

```
import socket,time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('',0))
port=s.getsockname()[1]
s.setblocking(0)
lines=[]
while True:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)

        if not lines:
            for client in clients:
                s.sendto(lines, client)
    except:
        pass
s.close()
```

I have paint application, in which the server sends the co-ordinates to a set of clients. I use the above code for sending, launching on a separate thread. This sends data to each client sequentially. This will cause a delay to the clients at the end of the list. Launching a separate thread for each client has scalability issues. Is there is scalabe way to write the above code maybe using async.io?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I rolled back your changes. Editing the question after it's been answered is against the Code Review chapter, because it invalidates the review. See the http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what you should and shouldn't do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `recvfrom` with a TCP socket (`SOCK_STREAM`). You don't see the error, because of your wrong exception handling. Never ignore all exceptions! Don't write your own server, use the appropriate interface from `asyncio`.

Comment: It should be `recv`instead? Which interface are talking about, please tell.

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: I want it to send data to all clients asynchronously.